# What is the Equivalent statement?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $x_0\in X$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, I have known that

$\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\leq a$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist an open neibourhood $U$ of $x_0$, such that for any $x\in U$, we have $f(x)<a+\epsilon$.

Then what is the equivalent statement of $\limsup\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\geq a$? And $\liminf\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\leq a$? If $\liminf\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)\geq a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\limsup \limits_{x \to x_0} f(x) \ge a$  $\iff $ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all neighborhoods $U$ of $x_0$ there is an $x \in U$ with $f(x) \ge a - \epsilon$.

Depending on your definition of the limes superior you might need to require $x \ne x_0$. The corresponding statements for the limes inferior follow from $\limsup \limits_{x \to x_0}-f(x) = - \liminf \limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$.